# Getting syntax error in Microsoft edge in javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, syntax, syntax-error, microsoft-edge

In Edge, I am running some await async code, and I keep getting a syntax error but it doesn't say what it specifically does not like about it. It works in Chrome too. In console of Edge I get

[image]

and when I click on it, it goes here

[image]

But I don't see why it is complaining about syntax.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: What is the double `await` supposed to even mean? o I c

Comment: you need one await for `import` and then another await for `.default()`. And it works on Chrome.

Comment: yea I see that now, and I agree it's mysterious

Comment: I think the error is pointing to `import` -- I don't think this is an asynchronous function, so you can't await it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) which is [not supported by Edge Legacy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility).

You could use it in Edge Chromium which can support dynamic import well. If you want to use it in Edge Legacy, you could try to use [dynamic-import-polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/dynamic-import-polyfill). It's a polyfill for dynamic `import()` that works in all module-supporting browsers.